# Monitoring EC2 disk metrics using aws mon scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using [aws mon scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/mon-scripts.html) for monitoring EC2 instances using following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
a="$(df | grep /dev/ | awk {'print $1'})"
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $a
#echo "${array[0]}"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
/opt/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --disk-space-util  --swap-util --disk-path="$element" --aws-credential-file=/opt/aws-scripts-mon/awscreds.template
done
```

Issue is it shows udev in cloudwatch for few machines instead of disk xvda1. Also,when I run this shell script in debug mode, it is compiled as xvda1 but passed to cloudwatch as udev.

Comment: did this solve your problem ? any feedback ?

Comment: Thanks . It works !!

Comment: thanks for accepting answer. It helps build my reputation. In general, request you to accept answer if it works and upvote it if it helped you on stackoverflow, this encourages us to build better community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the docs it states that you need to give the mount point.

> --disk-path=PATH Selects the disk on which to report.
>
> PATH can specify a mount point or any file located on a mount point
>   for the filesystem that needs to be reported

Your script is giving the file-system point where as if you see the df output we need to give mount point.

```
a="$(df | grep /dev/ | awk {'print $6'})"
```

This should solve your problem. So for xvda1 it will like this `--disk-path=/`